# javascript affecting both drop downs

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two drop downs, below is the code, my second dropdown is dependent to my first dropdown, so when i selected from first dropdown it will show options in second dropdown based on what i selected in the first. and then when i select an option from my second dropdown it will call a php page. but whats happening right now is when i select an option from my first dropdown, the page just refreshed and not giving option to select from second dropdown.

```
<tr>
<td align="center"><select name="Ticket" id="Ticket">
<option value="" selected="selected">Please Select...</option>
<option value="Option1">Option1</option>
<option value="Option2">Option2</option>
</select></td>

<tr>
<td align="center"><select name="Category" size="1" id="Category">
<option value="" selected="selected">--</option>
<option value="Select1.php" class="Option1">Select1</option>
<option value="Select2.php" class="Option2">Select2</option>
</select><input type="submit" value="Go" id="submit"/></td>
</tr>
```

and here is my js code so that second dropdown would call the php page,

**UPDATE:** i've updated the jquery and page is not refreshing when i select from my first dropdown but whats happening now is its trying to redirect the page already as soon as i selected from first dropdown...i want that to happen on my second dropdown and not on the first...

```
$(function() {

$("#submit").hide();

$("#form1 select").change(function() {
    window.location = $("#form1 select option:selected").val();
})
```

});

Comment: If you add an `alert("Category changed");` above the window.location line, is the alert triggered when you select something in the first dropdown? My guess is no. You probably have some listener somewhere else causing the page refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick.  The page will only redirect when you click the 'Go' button.

```
$(function () {
    $('#Ticket').change(function() {
        var optionClass = $(this).val();
        $('#Category option:not(:first)').hide();
        if (optionClass) {
            $('#Category').find('.' + optionClass).show();
        }
    });

    $('#submit').click(function () {
        window.location = $("#Category").val();
    });
});
```

If you want to redirect as soon as the second selectlist option is selected, replace the $('#submit').click.... with

```
$(function() {
    $('#Ticket').change(function() {
        var optionClass = $(this).val();
        $('#Category option:not(:first)').hide();
        if (optionClass) {
            $('#Category').find('.' + optionClass).show();
        }
    });

    $('#Category').change(function() {
        var url = $(this).val();
        if (url) {
            window.location = url;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: sorry, but would this work if i have too many options under select and want them all to be redirected on their own page?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - using the html in your question, it will work.  Select1 will redirect to Select1.php, Select2 to Select2.php and so on.  If you want more options, just add them using the same pattern.  Make sense?  Check this jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/L9dHy/

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$("#form1 select").change(function() {
    window.location = $("#form1 select option:selected").val();
})
```

to

```
$("#Category").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
})
```

Comment: `$("#Category").change(function() {
    window.location = $(this).val();
})` this is what i have from my original post and this is where my page just refreshed...